# Prove that only triangles, quadrilaterals, and hexagons will Tesselate the plane

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, tessellations

> Prove that only triangles, quadrilaterals, and hexagons will Tesselate the plane

So, I have almost completed the proof, I will write it down all the way to the part I'm stranded in.

Theorem: only triangles, quadrilaterals, and hexagons will Tesselate the plane

[image]

So, the angles of a regular polygon with $n$ sides have a measure of $(\frac{180(n-2)}{n})°$ when several "$n$-gons" meet at one point, $a$ angles meet, so the measure of all this a angles totals $(\frac{180(n-2)}{n}(a))°$; if $(\frac{180(n-2)}{n}(a))°>360°$ the polygons will overlap, whilst $(\frac{180(n-2)}{n}(a))°<360°$ will result in empty spaces. So
$$(\frac{180(n-2)}{n}(a))°=360°$$
which has to be simplified.

$\frac{180(n-2)}{n}(a)=360$

$180(n-2)a=360n$

$(n-2)a=2n$

$na-2a=2n$

$na-2a-2n=0$

$(a-2)n-2a=0$

So, this is this the immediately aforementioned linear system :

$\begin{bmatrix} (a-2) & -2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} n \\ a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Which I solve

$\begin{bmatrix} (a-2) & -2 & | & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{-2}{a-2} & | & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

So turns out

$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2t}{a-t} \\ t \end{bmatrix}$

But I get stuck in here; I know that $n$ is the number of sides of the $n$-gons we are tiling the plane with, and $a$ is the number of angles that meet at a point, so I know that I have to make sure that $a∈ℤ∧n∈ℤ∧n≥3$; I already know that this only happens when

$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$

and

$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ a \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$

But, I only do, because I know that beforehand; the only thing I'm missing to complete the proof, is that those are the only combinations that won't result in a number of sides or angles that make no sense.

How would you do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And pentagons as well

Comment: What do you even mean by $\begin{bmatrix} (a-2) & -2 & | & 0 \end{bmatrix}$? That's the only notation I don't know what is in your question.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming the scope of this problem only includes regular polygons.)

Most of your later steps are unnecessary. Once you have

$$a(n-2)=2n$$

or $(n-2)|2n$, we have

$$(n-2)|(2(n-2)+4).$$

$$(n-2)|4.$$

Comment: Yes, the scope is only regular polygons.